# How does <MinFilter=Linear> work in DirectX?

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, direct3d

The MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb322811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> D3DTEXF_LINEAR Bilinear interpolation filtering used as a texture magnification or minification filter. A weighted average of a 2 x 2 area of texels surrounding the desired 
>   pixel is used.

Is the weight of each texel is always 0.25 when `MinFilter=Linear` is set and the pixel is larger than the projected texel? If not ,how does DX calculate the weight of each texel?

Answer (score 1):

The weight is not always 0.25, the 4 texels are given appropriate weights based on the position of the sample point. In trilinear filtering (Min, Max and MipFilter=Linear) you get bilinear filtering for both the next larger and next smaller mip level and then you interpolate again with appropriate weights between those results.